# JavaScript assign value to input field, from selected option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to : OUTPUT value of selected OPTION, in a separate INPUT FIELD.
But, its not working and I am unable to determine what is wrong.

Code:

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/JavaScript">

      function validate()
      {
      var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
      var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("aid").value = selectedValue;
      //$("#aid").value = selectedValue;

      }
      </script>

      </head>
      <body>


      <select id="cardtype" name="cards" onChange="validate()">
      <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
      <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
      <option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
      <option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
      <option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
      </select><br/>

      <input type="text" id="aid" name="aid" />


      </body>
      </html>
```

What is the difference if I use:

```
document.getElementById("aid").innerHTML = selectedValue;
```

Comment: I just  checked it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cardtype").on("change", function(){
      $("#aid").val($('#cardtype').val());
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="cardtype" name="cards">
      <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
      <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
      <option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
      <option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
      <option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
      </select><br/>

      <input type="text" id="aid" name="aid" />
```

Please try this, I have updated your codes to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly, Check it over here.

```js
function validate()
{
      var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
      var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("aid").value = selectedValue;
 // document.getElementById("aid").innerHTML = selectedValue;
}
```

```html
   
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document    </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2  /jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="cardtype" name="cards" onChange="validate()">
<option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---    </option>
<option value="mastercard">Mastercard    </option>
<option value="maestro">Maestro    </option>
<option value="solo">Solo (UK only)    </option>
<option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron    </option>
<option value="visadebit">Visa Debit    </option>
</select>    <br/>
<input type="text" id="aid" name="aid" />
</body>
</html>
```

Setting the value is normally used for input/form elements. innerHTML is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

value applies only to objects that have the value attribute (normally, form controls).

innerHtml applies to every object that can contain HTML (divs, spans, but many other and also form controls).

They are not equivalent or replaceable. Depends on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You did everything ok. Just change this line..

```
var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
```

to this

```
var selectedValue = ddl.value;
```

```js
function validate() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
  var selectedValue = ddl.value;
  document.getElementById("aid").value = selectedValue;
  //$("#aid").value = selectedValue;

}
```

```html
<select id="cardtype" name="cards" onChange="validate()">
  <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
  <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
  <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
  <option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
  <option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
  <option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
</select>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="aid" name="aid" />
```